# Encrypt RSA, encode to string. On other end encode back to bytes and Decrypt RSA

Tags: c++, encoding, rsa, command-line-interface

I've been having trouble encoding RSA Encrypted bytes to string, and then getting them back to bytes on the other end(Remote host), the other end throws an exception of 'Bad Data'. 
I tried google, no luck.

My Code so far:

**Client**:

```
array<Byte>^Test=Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(Input);
array<Byte>^TempByteText=RSA->Encrypt(Test,false);
String^ TempString = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(TempByteText);
return TempString;
```

Then I send **TempString** to Server. Anything else I send, any text or bytes of any sort arrive on the other end as intended, but except for RSA Encrypted bytes.

**Server**:

```
array<Byte>^Test=Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(Input);
array<Byte>^TempByteText=RSA->Decrypt(Test,false);
return TempByteText;
```

Even if I return the functions locally, it's still says the same Bad Data. I have a 1024bit key, so the Encrypt size should be 128 bytes, which it **IS**, but it still say's 'Bad Data'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using RSA instead of a symmetric cipher such as AES, is this homework? RSA is about 1000 times slowed than AES and the data is limited to the key size with RSA bit not limited with AES. Also a 1024-bit key is really to small these days, you should use a 2048-bit or preferably 4096-bit key. RSA is no more secure than AES.

Comment: This is not homework lol. This is my personal project. Yes, I'am using AES also, but it works for AES, but doesn't for RSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypted data is not going to be ASCII, most of the bytes will fall into unprintable region, you need to convert to another encoding such as Base64 or hexadecimal if you need the encrypted data in String format.

Comment: I suspected as much, I just tested that Encoding is a lot faster than Base64, I just wanted confirmation that there is no possible way of using Encoding for this type of data. Thank you for your opinion.